# PHP session variable not changing value after navigation

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, session, twitter

I've got a few pages on my site where I pull through some organisation's twitter feed. I'm using Wordpress and I get their twitter handle using a custom field which loads dynamically based on which page / post you're on.

However, on my homepage I'm using our organisations twitter handle so you get general tweets from us and then specific organisation tweets on their profile pages.

This works fine until I navigate back to the homepage and then the tweets either taking far too long to load or don't load at all. I think it's something to do with my `$_SESSION['variable']` variable logic.

Here's my code `sessions.php` which I include in the `header.php` file which is on all of my website's pages.

```
session_start();

if(is_front_page()) {
    $_SESSION['twitter'] = "OurOrganisation";
}

else {
    // SET UP SINGLE ORG META DATA
    $_SESSION['twitter'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-twitter-usename', true);
}
```

And then this is the `tweets.php` page where I access my twitter OUTH tokens and encode the tweets into JSON for my jquery twitter feed.

```
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth-master/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");      //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = $_SESSION['twitter'];
$notweets = 30;
$consumerkey = "****";
$consumersecret = "****";
$accesstoken = "****";
$accesstokensecret = "****";


function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
unset($_SESSION['twitter']); // tidy up
```

Could anyone tell me what is causing this erratic behaviour described above? `$_SESSION['twitter']` is a textual value of a twitter handle / screen name.

Comment: Have you displayed your $_SESSION['twitter'] on your home page to make sure what is in it every time? And most important what is in it when the tweets fail.

Comment: Yes and it echos the correct "OurOrganisation" field.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question but why are you using sessions?  It appears you're setting the session every time (in `header.php`) and unsetting it every time in `tweets.php` - couldn't you just use a regular global variable in `header.php` instead of a session variable?